# CakePHP: Display multiple fields in a single drop down

Tags: cakephp, drop-down-menu, foreign-keys

```
$this->loadModel('Product');
$this->set('products',$this->Product->find('list',array('product'=>array('products.name' => 'products.price'))));
$this->set(compact('products'));
```

I am trying to make it so I can display both the product name and it's price beside each other in the function I am using. So when the drop down is selected, instead of just being "productname" it would be like "productname - $price".

I am pretty sure this is all the code that needsto be seen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple add the following line in your `Product Model`:

```
public $virtualFields = array('name_price' => 'concat(Product.name, "-", Product.price)');
```

and try the following code to fetch:

```
$this->loadModel('Product');
$this->set('products',$this->Product->find('list',array('fields'=>array('Product.name_price' => 'Product.price'))));
$this->set(compact('products'));
```

Comment: http://webdesign4.georgianc.on.ca/~100141468/comp2084/todo/orders/check   What do you think this error means?

Comment: Hold on I screw up and uploaded the wrong file and got a new error, sec

Comment: K there error is there SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Thanks, the last error is SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Product.' in 'field list' So I am scoping out a column called products?

Comment: Yes, you might check what are the actual field names in your products table. and provide those fields with the corresponding model name to avoid the ambiguity while executing your sql queries.

Comment: Yeah I am not sure where it is... I just have id and the foreign keys for billings, products and credits in the orders table. For pricing it has name and price there for it... Where would this column called Products be?

Comment: Never mind! Removed => 'Product.price' and it worked! Thanks for all the help!